# Parse server response in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse a server response which is a string

```
{"list":["23","87","34","67","34","3"]}
```

This is how I'm trying to parse it, but it doesn't work.

```
string resultContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var r = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<string>>(resultContent);
```

I've tried to find an example but usually json has a different structure so the examples didn't work.

Comment: Please post some sample code on what you've tried so far.

Comment: Sounds like you need to google "how to parse JSON in C#"

Comment: It's JSON. So use a JSON parser like JSON.Net. Also see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've posted some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the server response isn't *actually* a JSON object for a list of strings, but rather an object that has a `list` property, which is an array of strings.

While you *could* use something like [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to read the data into an object that you could access procedurally, I don't know of a way to do that within the BCL.

Thus, the simplest solution is to define a class that matches the definition of the data, and deserialize it into that.  If the server returns data in a variety of structures, you're probably better off using the Json.Net library I mentioned above, as creating type definitions for everything can quickly become tedious.

```
public sealed class ResponseModel
{
    public String[] list { get; set; }
}
```

Usage is the same as how you're already doing it, just replace `List<string>` with `ResponseModel`, like so:

```
var r = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ResponseModel>(resultContent);
```

Comment: And json2csharp.com is a very handy site to generate C#-classes from a given JSON string.